# Synonym request for [n-number] -> [aircraft-registration]

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

Could a mod create [n-number](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n-number) as a synonym of [aircraft-registration](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-registration)?

Unless anyone thinks otherwise?...

<sub>It's a common expression State-side, right?</sub>

Comment: Tail number or registration number work everywhere, N is a US centric and may spur the creation of many similar tags. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration for a list of the possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

"Tail number" is much more common.

I would also say that until we have a couple of instances where it's used, we probably don't need to worry about it. This seems a bit cart-before-the-horse.

Comment: And I think that "registration number" is the official term.  N-Number is US specific.